# Scipy optimize to target

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to optimize a function to get it as close to zero as possible.

The function is:

```py
def goal_seek_func(x: float) -> float:

    lcos_list_temp = [energy_output[i] * x for i in range(life)]
    npv_lcos_temp = npv(cost_capital, lcos_list_temp)

    total = sum([cost_energy_capacity,
                 cost_power_conversion,
                 balance_of_plant,
                 cost_construction_commissioning,
                 npv_o_m,
                 npv_eol,
                 npv_cost_charging,
                 npv_lcos_temp,
                 ])

    return total
```

All the variables calculated previously in the code.

It is a linear equation, where as `x` gets smaller, so does `total`.

I am trying to find the value of `x` where `total` is as close to `0` as possible.

I have tried to use:

```py
scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar(goal_seek_func)
```

but this clearly minimizes the equation to `-inf`. I have read the docs, but cannot see where to define a target output of the function. Where can I define this, or is there a better method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to find the value of x where total is as close to 0 as possible.

Then you want to solve the equation `goal_seek_func(x) = 0` instead of minimizing `goal_seek_func(x)`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71444472/4745529) for an explanation of why these two things are not the same. That being said, you can easily solve the equation by minimizing some vector norm of your objective function:

```py
res = scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar(lambda x: goal_seek_func(x)**2)
```

If the objective value `res.fun` is zero, `res.x` solves your equation. Otherwise, `res.x` is at least the best possible value.