# finding Intersection using scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, math, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to find x of intersection between two simple math functions using only scipy.optimize.minimize
I found the point successfully using (fsolve)

```
fsolve(lambda t: f1(t) - f2(t), x0)
```

but I'm limited to using only minimize and I couldn't find any solution,
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

minimize(lambda t: (f1(t) - f2(t))**2, x0)
```

should work. For a detailed explanation why, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71439717/how-to-use-scipy-optimize-minimize-to-find-travel-time-of-a-parameterized-curve/71444472#71444472) for instance.